# How to start jboss 7.1.1 server and deploy project in jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I use JBoss 7 server so I downloaded JBoss 7.1.1 version and unzip this zip file.

Then I go to bin folder and double click on `standalone.bat` but new cmd window open and close within 2 -3 sec.

If I run it using cmd, I get:

```
E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
```

then it stops.

So the JBoss server does not start.

How can I run JBoss server and deploy projects in it on Window 7?

Comment: run `run.bat` from cmd prompt.

Comment: E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>run.bat

=======================================================================================

To start JBoss Application Server please see E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\..\README.txt

========================================================================================

Comment: Try running the `standalone.bat` from the command line. IIRC `run.bat` is deprecated.

Comment: i try this but same problem , like E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give JAVA_HOME environment variable in your System Properties Environment Variables likes this;

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7
```

Comment: JBOSSֹ_HOME  is also required

Answer (score 3):

Give JBOSS_HOME environment variable in your System Properties Environment Variables likes this;

```
      E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try by putting your Java outside "Program Files". Sometimes commands fail because of the space in the path. Like your JAVA_HOME path is set to "C:\Program Files\Java" and hence it might be failing.

Please try to put Java folder directly under C:\ and set the JAVA_HOME variable (without bin) and also JBOSS_HOME variable in similar way (without bin).

Comment: this works...so bad these servers are developed on linux but are supported on windows...half majority of developers find easy to develop on windows rather than on linux..jboss should make it easy for windows developers...like apache tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried right clicking "cmd" and "Run as administrator"? Then cd to the folder and run it there...

or right click the bat file and "Run as administrator"?

I think usually starting server required administrator rights in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

It solved. Changing the java_home to c:\java\jdk1.6.0_23 and setting java_home environment variable to that route

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both JBOSS_HOME AND JAVA_HOME as explained above.