# Running jboss application server in windows

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I try to run j boss 7.1   according to read me  I go to j boss home and run standalone.bat
**\bin\standalone.bat**  then command prompt gives a massage"**calling \bin\standalone.conf.bat** " that's all please help me to fix this .I' m using windows 7 , inside the oracle virtual box

Comment: Try to set JAVA_HOME environment variable (and JBOSS_HOME if needed) as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260137/how-to-start-jboss-7-1-1-server-and-deploy-project-in-jboss-7-1-1.

Answer (score 0):

By using `\bin\standalone.bat` you're telling Windows that, assuming you're drive name is `C`, to look for the command in `C:\bin\standalone.bat`. If you're in the directory of your JBoss install, generally referred to as `JBOSS_HOME`, add a `.` to the beginning of the command.

Example:

```
.\bin\standalone.bat
```

If you do have a `JBOSS_HOME` directory set you could do:

```
%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\standalone.bat
```